# Why does AntlrWorks 2 display warning 125 (implicit definition of token in parser) in this case?

Tags: antlr4, antlrworks

I have a separate lexer and parser grammar (derived from the sample ModeTagsLexer/ModeTagsParser) and get a warning in AntlrWorks 2 that I don't understand:

warning(125): implicit definition of token OPEN in parser

If I replace the `OPEN` rule with `'<'` the warning goes away. I wonder what the difference between `OPEN` and `CLOSE` ist which get's no warning.

I'm using antlr-4.1-complete.jar and 2013-01-22-antlrworks-2.0.

Lexer STLexer.g4:

```
lexer grammar STLexer;

// Default mode rules (the SEA)
OPEN  : '<'     -> pushMode(ISLAND) ;       // switch to ISLAND mode
TEXT  : ~'<'+ ;                         // clump all text together

mode ISLAND;
CLOSE : '>'     -> popMode ; // back to SEA mode
SLASH : '/' ;
ID    : [a-zA-Z0-9"=]+ ;                     // match/send ID in tag to parser
WS    : [ \t]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

Parser STParser.g4:

```
parser grammar STParser;

options { tokenVocab=STLexer; } // use tokens from STLexer.g4



unit: (tag | TEXT)* ;

tag : OPEN ID+ CLOSE
    | OPEN SLASH ID+ CLOSE
    ;
```

It even persists if I rename the rule slightly and remove the additional mode:

```
lexer grammar STLexer;
```

Lexer (modified):

```
// Default mode rules (the SEA)
OPPEN  : '<'    ;// -> pushMode(ISLAND) ;       // switch to ISLAND mode
TEXT  : ~'<'+ ;                         // clump all text together

//mode ISLAND;
CLOSE : '>'  ; //   -> popMode ; // back to SEA mode
SLASH : '/' ;
ID    : [a-zA-Z0-9"=]+ ;                     // match/send ID in tag to parser
WS    : [ \t]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

Parser (modified):

```
parser grammar STParser;

options { tokenVocab=STLexer; } // use tokens from STLexer.g4



unit: (tag | TEXT)* ;

tag : ID OPPEN ID+ CLOSE
    | ID OPPEN SLASH ID+ CLOSE
    ;
```

Comment: This belongs here: https://bitbucket.org/sharwell/antlrworks2/issues